# Block a socket used by an agent

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm crawling an API. There is many many many requests. And if I do too much requests, the API starts by looking suspicious, and I get a bunch of 503. That's ok, when I get a 503 I've set a timer before re-running the request, and this timer is powered by two for each 503 of a same request.

BUT it doesn't work. Because my timer is asynchroneous. When I get the 503, after starting this timer, Node immediately reuse the socket for a pending request. So my timer basically doesn't change anything.

How can I prevent this ?

What I have tried so far :

- using a `settimeout` before restarting the request
- using the `sync` module, and its `pause` (does not work, because the fiber is asynchroneous

Any idea ? :<

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally come to the conclusion that it is not possible at this time.

In order to prevent massive flooding, I'm using the `queue` object of the `async` module. The code is something like that :

```
var queue = new Sync.Queue( function ( task, markAsComplete ) {
  Http.request( {
    agent : false, // we will use our own rate limiter, so we don't need agents
    ...
  }, function ( err, res ) {
    res.on( 'end', function ( ) {
      if ( IS_503 ) {
        var originalConcurrency = queue.concurrency; // saving the original concurrency
        queue.concurrency = 1;                       // our timeout will now stop every request
        setTimeout( function ( ) {
          queue.concurrency = originalConcurrency;   // restoring the concurrency
          queue.push( task );
          markAsComplete( );
        }, 1000 );
      }
    } );
  } );
}, numberOfParallelRequests );
```